# individual and overall file upload progress using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to create a multiple file upload control using ajax jquery. I do not want to using jquery file upload plugin or blueimp plugin.

Here is my code -

```
$("#upload").click(function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        data.append(selectedFiles[i].name, selectedFiles[i]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FileHandler.ashx",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        xhr: function () {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("There was error uploading files!");
        }
    })
    function progressHandlingFunction(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var s = Math.ceil(e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            console.log(s);
            progress(s, $('#progressBar'));
        }
    };        
});
```

I have to show individual and overall file upload progress similar like blueimp plugin. Could not fine any tutorial for it.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or correct my code?
How can we get error report when file upload fails and what is reason for it?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://codular.com/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress

Comment: I want to show progress for individual file and overall upload progress both.